# How to start ActiveMQ from applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am running a Spring project which has an applicationContext.xml which contains Camel routes that puts a message onto an ActiveMQ queue that was manually created. Before running the project,  I am manually starting the ActiveMQ server by logging into the folder activeMQ/bin and issuing the command activeMQ.

I would like to start ActiveMQ server from the applicationContext.xml . Can someone advice on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you or not, but I've done it the other way around. When starting my activemq instance, it also starts my camel routes.

If this is a viable solution in your case, follow these steps

1. Copy the jar file with your camel project as well as any third party libs to [activemq_home]/lib
2. At the bottom of [activemq_home]/conf/activemq.xml (assuming you are using the default    config), add  e.g.
3. Now start/restart activemq, and it should start your camel routes defined in the application context.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But I am looking to start ActiveMQ from Spring XML.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ provides support to start its broker in spring. Use the spring-activemq namespace to configure a broker inside spring's application context for details check spring support for activemq (http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html)

Comment: Thanks Hussain. After I configure my broker in spring and run the application, how do I ensure that the broker has started running?

Comment: Use the web-console to browse the broker (http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html)

Answer (score 0):

See this example

- http://camel.apache.org/activemq-camel-tomcat.html

Which demonstrates how to embed an ActiveMQ broker in a Spring XML file.

You can also find some details on the ActiveMQ documentation such as

- http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html